# Local groups in windows XP, SQL is not showing

Tags: sql, windows-xp, usergroups

I am using windows xp SP3 and in that I want to give SQL related rights to a user. But in local groups I dont see any group related to SQL. I have installed SQL server 2000 in the PC. What may be the problem?

Thanks,
Kbv.

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

1. You can either create a sql login and associate with one of the windows / active directory groups.
2. You can create a new group in windows / active directory and do as above.
3. (Less better) - Create a user in SQL and log into it with that - no windows users.

You do really need to read up / run a short course on SQL user permissions and security.

Maybe look at:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1831/using-windows-groups-for-sql-server-logins-as-a-best-practice/ 
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/sql-database-fundamentals-16944